# Android Gravity Left vs Right Clipping Difference

Tags: android, layout

I'm seeing a difference in clipping between a left aligned and a right aligned TextView that I don't understand.

Here's a sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_message_content_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="@color/blue">

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_message_content_container"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_message_content_container"
            android:text="This is a long sample label string"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This gives me the layout I expect:

[image: Left Alignment OK]

The caption label is below the 'Hello World'. But if I change this so that android:gravity="right" and use layout_alignRight instead of layout_alignLeft, the caption view gets clipped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_message_content_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="@color/blue">

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_message_content_container"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout_message_content_container"
            android:text="This is a long sample label string"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And now the caption view is clipped to the width of the view above it.

[image: Right-Aligned with Clipping]

How can I have this view right-aligned to the view above it but not clipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_message_content_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="This is a long sample label string" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Same UI with `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="This is a long sample label string"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hello_world" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Cool - start & end vs left & right makes the difference.  Still don't understand why the original method wasn't working but thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah. Always use `start` and `end` to support RTL layouts. I actually tried `start` and `end` but strangely it didn't work in existing code.